# Extract rows and save to multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to solve the following problem using Python: I've a table (csv) from which I want to extract consecutively row 1 + 2, then row 1 + 3, then row 1 + 4, etc. The extracts should be saved again as csv file and named according to the first string in the  2nd row to be extracted (2, 3, 4, 5,...). Now my question - is python the right tool to do this and is there any example code available?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help & hints!

Claude S.

### + Clarification:

Thanks for the feedback - actually I was trying to use the csv module to open and read the table using this code:

```
import csv
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

---

Now I am not sure how to select and write the required rows... sorry for the beginners kind of question.
Claude S.

Comment: Which specific part of this are you having issues with?

Comment: The [documents](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) include examples. If you've checked that `csv.reader` works and you want to write then look into `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fname = argv[1]
with open(fname) as i:
    reader = csv.reader(i)

    first_row = next(reader)
    for cur_row in reader:
        out_name = cur_row[0]
        with open(out_name, 'wb') as o:
            writer = csv.writer(o)
            writer.writerow(first_row)
            writer.writerow(cur_row)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that you need the csv module (unless the first column could contain quotes and commas). If your file format is simple, just use split.

```
fname = argv[1]
with open(fname) as f:
    header = f.readline()
    # parse the rest of the lines. 
    for line in f:
        out_name = line.split(',')[0]
        with open(out_name, 'wb') as o:
            o.write(header)
            o.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint - indeed the csv module was not necessary - with local support I got the this solution: